# Эмуляция LPT,COM,USB портов

Tags: windows, usb, железо, com-порт, lpt

Нужна программа, которая бы помогла в отладке моего приложения.
Приложение собственно предназначено для работа с LPT (в будущем COM,USB) портами.
Чтобы проверить данную программу мне необходимо наличие на материнке LPT порта. Но так как у меня нету на материнке компьютера LPT порта, требуется реализовать, точнее эмулировать программно нужный мне порт. 
Есть ли такой софт который мог бы показать (эмулировать) мне LPT порт и при работе порта (PINов) соответственно указывать какой PIN врубился и вырубился..

Comment: Какая операционная система?

Comment: Использую Windows

Comment: ЕМНИП при подключении USB2LPT донгла драйвер полностью эмулирует LPT-порт, включая нормальную работу через порты ввода-вывода. Пошарь по Инету, стопудово кто-то на таком пробовал отлаживаться.